# regex - replace ordered list of lines matching a string with another list

Tags: regex, sed, awk, subtitles

I have such confused ideas I couldn't describe well the problem synthetically, hence the title is horrible. Suggest me a better one too, while you're at it.

Basically, I have two SubRip (.srt) subtitles with the same number of lines. They are in different languages and I need to sync them.

Point syncing one to the other doesn't give a good enough result, because the second one apparently have some bad timed lines. What I want to do is copying timestamps from the first to the second.

Given that some lines have a line break, the timings are not cadenced with a fixed pattern. To get the lines with the timings, I should look for the arrow going from start time to end time.

> 1.srt

```
1
00:00:01,336 --> 00:00:03,437
Foo

2
00:00:03,440 --> 00:00:05,093
Bar
Baz

3
00:00:05,096 --> 00:00:07,330
Qux
```

> 2.srt

```
1
00:00:01,336 --> 00:00:03,935
Quux

2
00:00:03,936 --> 00:00:05,201
Garply
Waldo

3
00:00:05,803 --> 00:00:07,467
Fred
```

```
more 1.srt | grep -- "-->"

00:00:01,336 --> 00:00:03,437
00:00:03,440 --> 00:00:05,093
00:00:05,096 --> 00:00:07,330

more 2.srt  | grep -- "-->"

00:00:01,336 --> 00:00:03,935
00:00:03,936 --> 00:00:05,201
00:00:05,803 --> 00:00:07,467
```

How can I replace the lines containing the timestamps in `1.srt` with the corresponding ones of `2.srt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's name the files descriptively: `good-text` and `good-times`.

1. Isolate lines with timestamps from `good-times`:

   ```
   grep -- '-->' good-times > the-ringer
   ```
2. Let `awk` replace wrong timestamps:

   ```
   < good-text awk '
      { if ($2 == "-->") getline < "the-ringer"
      print }
   ' > good-all
   ```

   Each time `awk` encounters a line where the second field is `-->` it replaces it with a line from `the-ringer`.
3. Get rid of <strike>Walter's dirty undies</strike> garbage: `rm the-ringer`.

Examine `good-all`, it should contain what you want. The whole procedure could be done solely with `awk` but I decided to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Can't give enough upvotes for the Lebowski reference. And, as an Arch Linux user, the KISS principle is very dear to me. Thank you, and a good day to you, sir!